# Displaying pdf files using the PDFKit interface

Tags: cocoa, pdf, macos-sierra, pdfview, pdf-annotations

I am working on a Mac OS 10.12, and have an application to display pdf files using the PDFKit interface.
But I encountered the following **issues**

> Set pdf document to PDFView, in original OS,e.g. OS10.11 , there will invoke PDFView->drawPage() function, but in OS10.12,the function is not invoked;
>
> `PDFView can't draw pdf annotation in OS10.12;`

Solution to the above will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I reckon this is either a straight out bug or an as yet undocumented API change. I logged this as a bug (27666426) and can see now that it is being flagged as an open duplicate (27668895).

Note that of 10.12 Beta 6 `-drawWithBox:toContext:` gets called in place of the now deprecated `-drawWithBox:`. Note that it is also necessary to use the passed in context for all drawing.

UPDATE:

However things do not seem that simple with the 10.12 now that it is released. I find that my PDF view printing, which is driven off of `-drawWithBox:` on 10.11 and `-drawWithBox:toContext:` on 10.12+ is broken.

Stepping through the assembler I can see that 10.12, when printing, now calls `-drawWithBox:inContext:` not `-drawWithBox:toContext:` or `-drawWithBox:` (as was the case on 10.11). It would seem that the `inContext:` selector has been [around a while](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/178803-pdfmarkupannotations-not-showing-when-drawing-pdfpage.html).

It would seem that the only solution that works on 10.9 - 10.12 for both screen and print renders is to use the undocumented  `-drawWithBox:inContext:`.

Comment: Now the latest os10.12 operating system, PDF annotation can be displayed, but now I still have a problem, I recorded coordinate information in PDFView ->mouseDragged before, and then automatically will invoke the PDFView->drawPage function, this function I will draw the NSBezierPath curve to determine the dynamic annotation bounds. but now in the process of mouseDragged has not been call the drawPage:toContext function. I use the refresh method is still not invoke drawPage:toContext. would like to know how to call this function. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't use annotations, I just draw directly onto the view. Have you reviewed how [skim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/skim-app/) handles annotations? I know they had some issues on 10.12.

Comment: I got this problem too. I found when I zoom in or zoom out, the annotation will show. But I don't know how to make it dynamic display. It seems the SetNeedsDisplay doesn't work.

Comment: There is a new PDFAnnotation method `- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary 
                           forPage:(PDFPage *)page;`. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Check out the updates above as well as http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/178803-pdfmarkupannotations-not-showing-when-drawing-pdfpage.html

Comment: @Jonathan Mitchell How to set the NSDictionary? What's that? Thanks

Comment: See the header info in PDFKit/PDFAnnotation.h. I don't think it will resolve the issue.

Comment: And I also found the PDFThumbnailView Outlets to the PDFView but the PDFThumbnailView doesn't show pages.... confused...

Comment: @Jonathan Mitchell I have tried your modified answer but I cannot see the -drawWithBox:inContext: method in Xcode...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124839/discussion-between-superberry-and-jonathan-mitchell).