# Unable to display pdf annotations with PDFKit (macOS Sierra bug?)

Tags: pdf, macos-sierra, setneedsdisplay

I am working with PDFKit on macOS 10.12 and Xcode 8.0. I am creating some annotations in a pdf, displayed using PDFView, but I am not able to see them once created, unless to force the refreshing of the view through **zomming in and out inside the page**.

I have written a Minimal Working Example that [you can clone from here](https://github.com/LucaMarconato/PDFKitBug)

If you clone it in your root folder the code will run, otherwise remember to change `pdfPath` to the path of an existing pdf.

Additional details on the problem:
[Add pdf annotation with PDF Kit in OS 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784953/add-pdf-annotation-with-pdf-kit-in-os-10-12) (it seems that there is a workaround of the problem but I am not been able to implement it, may you are

[PDFView setNeedsDisplay:YES doesn't work on MacOS Sierra 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868300/pdfview-setneedsdisplayyes-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra-10-12) (same problem, they did not solve it)

[Displaying pdf files using the PDFKit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517984/displaying-pdf-files-using-the-pdfkit-interface) (same workaround suggested in the first link, but I am still not able to use it. The answer continued in a chat and so I cannot see how they managed)

Last but maybe not less important, Xcode gives me this warning (maybe solving it the problem would solve, but I cannot find an exhaustive documentation that teaches how to manage it):
[image: here]

Thank you in advance for all the precious answers.

[image: Screenshot of the minimal working example that I have linked]

Comment: I got the same problem. I have report this to the bug report of Apple, but they didn't response yet.

Comment: Did you report this to Apple?